# how to get/print CATALINA_OPTS

Tags: java, tomcat7, config

I know we can set/add a property to tomcat catalina opts by using set or export command.
But how do I get or print all the properties set in CATALINA_OPTS as well as their values?
I checked online but couldn't really find a way to print the values. Thanks!

Comment: In a Windows commandline use `set CATALINA_OPTS` in a Linux shell use `echo $CATALINA_OPTS`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks! That is giving me any properties that I set through the set/export command. But what about the properties that are part of CATALINA_OPTS specified in a properties file/appended from the startup .sh script? They are not getting printed with echo command!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case if you want to view all environment variables...

... in Windows, type `set` in command prompt.

... in Mac / Linux, type `env` in Terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't normally suggested editing the standard Tomcat scripts but in this case it is probably the simplest approach.

Look in catalina.[sh|bat] for where CATALINA_BASE and friends are echo'd to the console and add a line to echo CATALINA_OPTS.